# Anyone can help me in gradle building problem?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some compiling problem but just don't know why...... I successfully build some programs before but after I change something, all program just failed. Can anybody tell me what's this problem? very very thankful...

> - Where: Build file '/home/wildfire/my_workspace/ajpf_ros/build.gradle'
>   line: 11
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ajpf_ros'.
>   Cause: Could not find method maven()
>   for arguments
>   [build_3bcu47ed6p0s77r3m7ndupfh7r$_run_closure1_closure3@1ec3c6d]
>   on root project 'ajpf_ros'.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>   or --debug option to get more log
>   output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 4.096 secs

I've checked other program and it seems like not a "gradle building problem". Is this error come from my wrong code? It's just a very simple one extended from tutorial.

The gradle.build is

> ```
> apply plugin: 'java'
>
> apply plugin: 'maven'
>
> apply plugin: 'application'
> mainClassName = 'org.ros.RosRun'
>
> sourceCompatibility = 1.6
> targetCompatibility = 1.6
>
> repositories {
>   mavenLocal()
>   maven {
>     url 'http://robotbrains.hideho.org/nexus/content/groups/ros-public'
>   }
> }
>
> version = '0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
> group = 'ros.my_stack'
>
> dependencies {
>   compile 'ros.rosjava_core:rosjava:0.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
> }
> ```

```
 wildfire@ubuntu:~/my_workspace/ajpf_ros$ gradle --version

 Gradle 1.0-milestone-3

 Gradle build time: Thursday, September
 8, 2011 4:06:52 PM UTC Groovy: 1.7.10
 Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2
 compiled on August 19 2011 Ivy: non
 official version JVM: 1.6.0_24 (Sun
 Microsystems Inc. 20.0-b12) OS: Linux
 3.0.0-24-generic i386
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41882/anyone-can-help-me-in-gradle-building-problem?/) by [wildfire](https://answers.ros.org/users/2576/wildfire/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-08-21**:
Please describe in detail what you are doing before getting the error, see http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2012-08-21**:
The java code also has plenty of problems, but those have nothing to do with the error you get. Please also run the gradle / gradlew command that you use with --version, and post the result here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll be more successfull searching for answers regarding gradle if you just use google:

Maybe this helps:
http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_build_error_in_sts

You use gradle 1.0-milestone-3. As the link above says, you need at least gradle 1.0-milestone-5. So your gradle version is just too old. Use the gradlew wrapper from rosjava_core as it says in the tutorial.

You can also get the gradlew wrapper by running:

```
$ hg clone https://code.google.com/p/rosjava
```

Anywhere on your disk, and copying the file 'gradlew' and the 'gradle' directory to your project, and then always using that gradlew instead of just gradle.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably did not apply the maven plugin.

http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-08-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1